# Extra / appears in page from php hidden input post

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<input type='hidden' name='projectid' value=".$row['ProjectID']. "/>
```

Which would product an extra / in the result
but if I erase the / in the input form like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='projectid' value=".$row['ProjectID']. ">
```

there there is no extra / and no error.

Any idea why? I think /> is correct to close a input ?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code that you are working with?

Comment: may be problem is in your quotes,ur code should be `<?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='projectid' value='".$row['ProjectID']. "'/>" ?>`

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem in the syntax of

```
<input type='hidden' name='projectid' value=".$row['ProjectID']. ">
```

If you want to give value of PHP variable to html tags, you have to echo them like,

```
<input type='hidden' name='projectid' value="<?php echo $row['ProjectID']; ?>" />
```